# How to prevent ScrollViewer from using MouseWheel event

Tags: silverlight, scrollbar, zooming, scrollviewer

I'm building SL application for zooming and panning across the layout. Everything is working fine, except that when I zoom in using mouse wheel , after some zoom scrollbars start to use mouse wheel so after that I can scroll not zoom. I only can zoom again if I put scrollbars at the end or begining. How to prevent scrollviewer from using mouse wheel? I want that zoom only be operated by wheel. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code of MouseWheel method when I'm zooming content :

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e) 
    { 
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);             

        if (e.Delta > 0) 
        { 
            this.aniScaleX.To += 0.2; 
            this.aniScaleY.To += 0.2; 

            this.sbScale.Begin(); 
        } 
        else if (e.Delta < 0 && (this.aniScaleX.To > 1 && this.aniScaleY.To > 1)) 
        { 
            this.aniScaleX.To -= 0.2; 
            this.aniScaleY.To -= 0.2; 

            this.sbScale.Begin(); 
        } 

        Sizer.Width = Board.ActualWidth * (double)this.aniScaleX.To; 
        Sizer.Height = Board.ActualHeight * (double)this.aniScaleY.To;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable mouse wheel scrolling in scrollviewer wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568220/disable-mouse-wheel-scrolling-in-scrollviewer-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **MouseWheel event is a bubbling
>   event**. This means that if multiple
>   MouseWheel event handlers are
>   registered for a sequence of objects
>   connected by parent-child
>   relationships in the object tree, the
>   event is potentially received by each
>   object in that relationship. The
>   bubbling metaphor indicates that the
>   event starts at the source and works
>   its way up the object tree. For a
>   bubbling event, the sender available
>   to the event handler identifies the
>   object where the event is handled, not
>   necessarily the object that actually
>   received the input condition that
>   initiated the event. To get the object
>   that initiated the event, use the
>   OriginalSource value of the event
>   data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousewheel(VS.95).aspx

In my case,ScrollViewer always received event before because he is on the top of the visual tree. So I just registered event handler in scrollviewer on mouse wheel event and always when It happens, I simply redirect him to my "original" mousewheel function which do zoom.

I hope so that this will help somebody who is "stuck" like me here. Thank you all on your answers and suggestions..

Answer (score 5):

Try to set:

```
e.Handled=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

This took me awhile (WPF), but basically you should use AddHandler in whatever parent UIElement that has the event.

For me, I did this in my MainWindow.  So my code looked like:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AddHandler(MainWindow.MouseWheelEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.MouseWheel_1), true);
}
```

This will also mean not overriding OnMouseWheelDown, but instead creating a method that matches the RoutedEventHandler delegate and casting e (which will be a RoutedEventArg) as MouseWheelEventArgs to get access to the properties required to determining zoom.

I hope this helps for your situation.