# disable mouse wheel scrolling in scrollviewer wpf

Tags: wpf, scroll, scrollbar, scrollviewer, mousewheel

In xaml code

```
<StackPanel>
 <ScrollViewer>
  <local:CustomCanvas>
  </local:CustomCanvas>
 </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

CustomCanvs has a zoom in/out function. But when I spin the mouse wheel in the CustomCanvas area, ScrollViewer's scrollbar works and zoom in/out don't work.  And when I scroll the scrollbar of the ScrollViewer, not only CustomCanvas' zoom in/out work but also scrolling of the ScrollViewer work well.

When I spin the mouse wheel, I want only zoom in/out. And when I scroll the scrollbar, I want only scrolling to work.

How I can prevent mouse wheel event of ScrollViewer from spining mouse wheel?
And how I can prevent zoom in/out from scrolling of ScrollViewer's scrollbar?
Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could handle the MouseWheel Event of Custom Canvas so that when the mouse is pointed in your canvas area and the wheeling event accured you set the Handled property of the MouseWheelEventArgs to true :

```
 private void UIElement_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        //handler your zoomIn/Out here
    }
```

and in the Xaml

```
<StackPanel>
 <ScrollViewer>
  <local:CustomCanvas  MouseWheel="UIElement_OnMouseWheel">
  </local:CustomCanvas>
 </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thankyou.  I already did that.  I have child Image and TextBlock in CustomCanvas.  Only if i spin mouse wheel on the child of CustomCanvas, it work...  Why MouseWheel event not accure in other area of CustomCanvas except of child area?  In other area, wheel event accure for ScrollViewer so scroll work.