# Zoom to mouse position inside a scrollview

Tags: wpf, zooming, scrollviewer, reactiveui

So I've done a ZoomControl that uses a border and an image

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageViewer.Controls.ZoomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageViewer.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Border x:Name="BorderImage">
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="RenderingImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0"  Stretch="None" Source="{Binding}" RenderTransform="{Binding}"/>
    </Border>
```

This control is nested inside a ScrollViewer

```
   <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScollViewerImage"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">            
            <Controls:ZoomControl x:Name="RenderingImage" ViewModel="{Binding}" ClipToBounds="True"></Controls:ZoomControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

So I've built a zoom to mouse position function

```
private void DoZoom(double deltaZoom, Point mousePosition)
        {
            var scaleTransform = GetScaleTransform();
            var translateTransform = GetTranslateTransform();

            if (!(deltaZoom > 0) && (scaleTransform.ScaleX < .4 || scaleTransform.ScaleY < .4))
                return;

            var mousePositionAfterScaleX = mousePosition.X * deltaZoom;
            var mousePositionAfterScaleY = mousePosition.Y * deltaZoom;

            var newMousePositionX = mousePosition.X - mousePositionAfterScaleX;
            var newMousePositionY = mousePosition.Y - mousePositionAfterScaleY;

            var newTranslateX = newMousePositionX - mousePosition.X;
            var newTranslateY = newMousePositionY - mousePosition.Y;

            var translateX = newTranslateX + translateTransform.X;
            var translateY = newTranslateY + translateTransform.Y;

            scaleTransform.ScaleX += deltaZoom;
            scaleTransform.ScaleY += deltaZoom;

            _currentZoom = scaleTransform.ScaleX;   

            ChangeTranslateTransofrm(translateX - overflowWidth, translateY - overflowHeight);
            UpdateScaleTransfromValue();
        }
```

This works fine as long as the image fits inside the ScrollViewer size. But after the image is bigger than the ScrollVIewer control ( it shows up the scrollbars) and whenever I zoom in my mouse position is no more on the same point. I am sure it has something to do with the fact that the scrollbar are visible, but I can't figure out the math to make the mouse stick to the same position after scrollbar are visible.

Comment: Have you consider about a key combination for zoom event? Such as `Ctrl` + `wheel up` to zoom in, so you can tell that the user is trying to ZOOM instead of SCROLL

Comment: Hello, yes the zoom is already done using the Ctrl. I found the problem it's somewhere inside the ScrollViewer and the fact that scrollbar are on auto mode. I added 2 borders that will occupy the space of the scrollbars when they are not visible. And made sure the scrollbar position persist on zoom in zoom out ( it has an VerticalOffset/HorizonatlOffset) of 48 on my case.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568220/disable-mouse-wheel-scrolling-in-scrollviewer-wpf

Comment: @ViperLiu no, that's not what I intend. I want the scroll wheel to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after 2 days of try and error I've found the solution for my specific problem. First of all there are 2 main problems.

1. Scrollbars are on auto ( they hide/show at run time based on the width.height of the child inside the **ScrollViewer** ). Because of that the image inside changes it's translate transform.
2. The scrollbar position (offset) does not persist on the same position after a zoom/in out action(child get bigger or smaller).

First problem was solved by adding 2 borders to the ScrollViewer that will keep the space needed for scrollbar occupied as long as the scrollbars are not visibile.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScollViewerImage" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=ScollViewerImage}"
                                         Value="Visible">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight}">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=ScollViewerImage}"
                                         Value="Visible">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>
            <Controls:ZoomControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="RenderingImage" ViewModel="{Binding}" ClipToBounds="True"></Controls:ZoomControl>
        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

For the second problem whenever a scroll is done I save the offset. 
I also sahve  the zoom size (ScrollableHeight and Scorllable Width) and when they change (Zoom in/zoom out has been done). I reposition the scrollbar at is desired position.

```
        private void SetScrollbarOffset(ScrollViewer scrollViewer, double verticalChange, double horizontalChange)
        {
            // after each move of the scrollbar we save the current offsets
            _currentVerticalOffset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
            _currentHorizonalOffset = scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;

            // we check if there was a zoom in/out perfomed
            if (_scrollableHeight != scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
            {
                // we save the current zoom in/out scrollable height
                _scrollableHeight = scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
                // we move the scrollbar to the position needed to persist the mouse under the same point in the image
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_currentVerticalOffset - verticalChange);
            }

            if (_scrollableWidth != scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth)
            {
                _scrollableWidth = scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth;
                scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(_currentHorizonalOffset - horizontalChange);
            }
        }
```

This last method is called from SizeChangedEvent

```
        public void SizeChange(ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var scrollViewer = (e.OriginalSource as ScrollViewer);

            SetScrollbarOffset(scrollViewer, e.VerticalChange, e.HorizontalOffset);
        }
```