# Why is my WPF mousewheel/previewmousewheel event still getting through after setting e.handled?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a C# WPF application with a User Control displayed inside a ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" MouseWheel="ScrollViewer_MouseWheel">
<Drawing:DrawingWindow Name="Drawing" MouseWheel="Drawing_MouseWheel" PreviewMouseWheel="Drawing_PreviewMouseWheel"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I've tried putting an event-handler for all scroll-related events both on the contained element and the ScrollViewer itself. Each of the handlers is basically just this:

```
private void Drawing_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}

private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}

private void Drawing_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}

private void ScrollViewer_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Even with all this, the vertical scroll-bar still responds to the mouse-wheel when I scroll on top of the Drawing element.

What am I doing wrong? I've seen a lot of posts where setting e.handled appears to be the solution:

[Disable mouse wheel scrolling in scrollviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568220/disable-mouse-wheel-scrolling-in-scrollviewer-wpf)

Comment: You linked to a post containing an answer to your question, but didn't follow its advice.  It doesn't say "Handle the ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel event or the Drawing_MouseWheel event," it says "handle the MouseWheel Event of Custom Canvas so that when the mouse is pointed in your canvas area and the wheel event occurs you can set the Handled property of the MouseWheelEventArgs to true."

Comment: DrawingWindow in this question is equivalent to CustomCanvas in the other one. The DrawingWindow mouse wheel events are handled like the CustomCanvas mouse wheel events.